# Find image under Riemann map without the explicit map

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I find the image of the line segments $(0,1)$ and $(0,1+i)$ under the unique Riemann map $f$ from the square with vertices at $\pm1\pm i$ onto the unit disc satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)>0$ ?

By line segment $(a,b)$ I mean the set $\{ z\in\mathbb{C}: z= a+t(b-a), 0<t<1 \}$.

Comment: What is a Riemann map? A map you use you to prove the Riemann mapping theorem? At any rate you might be interested in the book "Visual Complex Analysis" by Tristam Needham. Check out his "amplitwist" concept.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: by symmetry.

Under the given normalization, $f$ is unique. Yet, $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)}$ has all the   properties that $f$ has. This, $\overline{f(\bar z)} = f$ for all $z$ in the domain.  The same applies to other symmetries such as reflection about $y=x$, written as $z\mapsto i\bar z$.

Thus, the image of an axis of symmetry of the square is a diameter of the disk. This implies that the images of the line segments mentioned are radii of the disk.  To identify these radii, look at the behavior of $f$ near $0$, which is governed by $f'(0)>0$.